# Server Public/Private Folders Security

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, httpd.conf

So i have read a few things about keeping files out of the public view and to only keep the necessary file in public view and move all functions files, etc., into a private folder outside of the root.

I do not have access to the httpd conf file so I cannot change my document root in the conf file. I would like to change my document/web root as follows:

```
from /public_html 
to /public_html/public
```

and then put all my private/protected files in

```
/public_html/private
```

I know I can do this in my conf file but I do not have access to it. I use whm cpanel on virtual private server. They require using "includes" which i do not know much about or how to implement.

My question is, if i simply change my .htaccess file to rewrite my root to the new root will this accomplish the same security measure?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Does the .htaccess rewrite accomplish the same security measure or do I have to change my httpd conf file in order to achieve this security?

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer is yes, but it's a bit convoluted. I'd rather use the original document root and put the files you don't want to be accessed one level below. Most hostings give you access to the parent folder.

Comment: so you are saying keep all public stuff in /public_html/ and create another folder /private/ and keep all private stuff there?

Comment: Yes, since `public_html` is already a subfolder of your user home directory, and you probably have access to the home itself, there's no point trying to hack a fake private folder accessible from the web but made private using rewrite rules. Just keep it out of document_root